# jbpm 6.0.1 create process calling rest

Tags: rest, process, jbpm, bpmn, workbench

How to create process with 1 service task - rest which calls 
http://www.webservicex.net/currencyconvertor.asmx/ConversionRate?FromCurrency=EUR&ToCurrency=USD
and sets this value as parameter which can be seen later, using jbpm console(kie workbench)? JBOSS docs are mostly for user tasks.

Answer (score 1):

My recommended solution is to create a new WorkItemHandler implementation that calls the web service get the results and inject that as a process variable. 
You can see a similar example that calls web services here: https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm-playground/tree/master/customer-relationships-workitems

HTH

Answer (score 0):

There is a REST service task that you can use, available out-of-the-box in the web-based designer (under service tasks, so implemented as a custom service task).  The associated handler should also be registered automatically when using the jbpm-installer:
https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm/blob/master/jbpm-installer/conf/META-INF/CustomWorkItemHandlers.conf#L4